# Testing ag-grid with @testing-library/react

Tags: ag-grid, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test component which use ag-grid.

When I do assertions to check if cells with given text are rendered I receive the following error:

`expect(received).toBeInTheDocument() received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement. Received has type: object
Received has value: HERE IS EXPECTED HTML FOR THE CELL I'VE BEEN LOOKING FOR`

I have created code sandbox for this issue (see `grid.test.tsx`) https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-silence-4l1s1

Comment: Does it fail in local too?

Comment: Thanks @GiorgioPolvara-Gpx, I've managed to run it on local with some changes in my configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like ag-grid does something to the DOM. After rendering ag-grid inside the test it breaks all assertion which check the dom (even for elements outside grid!) when used in codesandbox. I understand that codesandbox is using real browser dom instead of jsdom.

I managed to make it work on my local machine, but I had to switch to jsdom 14 (check https://github.com/ianschmitz/jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen).

I've also needed to add this code in my tests setup (ag-grid is using `innerText` instead of `textContent`, without it I had no text inside rendered cells)

```
Object.defineProperty(global.window.Element.prototype, 'innerText', {
  set(value) {
    this.textContent = value;
  },
  configurable: true
})
```